# what can i use as a generic of List so i can change the type within the list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

so i currently have

```
class general
private list as List(Of string) 

public overridable function getprivateList as <not sure what to put>
    return list
end function
end class

class specific inherits general
private list as List(Of listofstrings)

end class
```

but I cannot figure out what to use as an interface .
so that the method getprivateList is able to return both variations of list, depending on the class of implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return `IEnumerable`, `ICollection`, or `IList`.  `IEnumerable` has the least functionality and `IList` has the most.

```
Class General
    Private list As List(Of String) 

    Public Overridable Function GetPrivateList() As IList
        Return list
    End Function
End Class

Class Specific 
    Inherits General
    Private list As List(Of Integer)
End Class
```

Alternatively, you could define your base class as a generic class which takes the type of list item:

```
Class General(Of T)
    Private list As List(Of T) 

    Public Overridable Function GetPrivateList() As List(Of T)
        Return list
    End Function
End Class

Class Specific 
    Inherits General(Of Integer)
End Class
```